# Zabbix notifing about last 3 abnormal values

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to achieve somthing like that in Zabbix:
there is some data coming into one item in Zabbix, the threshold is of values is 15. I want to detect situation when last three values of the item are above the threshold, for example: 16, 17, 18, and then send the e-mail about that event. I do know how to configure items and actions, but I don't know how to configure trigger expression.
I use something like that:

```
{test_trigger:test_item.last(#1)}>15&
{test_trigger:test_item.last(#2)}>15&
{test_trigger:test_item.last(#3)}>15
```

but this expression sends emails always, when last three values are above the limit, which I don't want to achieve. My expectation is something like that: after recieving three values above the threshold, send e-mail and reset the trigger.

Comment: Could you please describe the use case that you want to solve? Maybe what you really want can be solved in a different way? For instance, is it true that what you really want is to delay notifications and send an alert if the trigger has been active for at least 10 minutes?

Comment: Maybe it is not clear, so I try to be more specific: When item recieves three values above threshold, the trigger should fire an action, but with expression given above it works like that: 3 values come, trigger fires, and when the 4th matching value comes and trigger fires again (because condition is satisfied)

Comment: The initial description was perfectly clear regarding the mathematical part, but gave no indication about the real-world problem you were trying to solve. Since the mathematical part was a bit unusual (why would anybody want to force a trigger reset after reporting a problem?), I asked about the real-world problem you were solving, because perhaps it could be solved differently.

Comment: It's all about number of processes on one virtual machine - when it exceeds some given number three times in a row, it should send a notice to administrator. VM sends the number of processes each 5 minutes continuously.

Comment: But why do you need to force the trigger reset? Why not let it become OK itself when the number of processes goes below the threshold again? As far as I understand, your problem is that you do not want to receive an email every 5 minutes - you only wish to receive an email once, when the number of processes exceeded the threshold for the first time. If so, you should simply uncheck "Multiple PROBLEM events generation" checkbox (see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/triggers/trigger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following trigger expression:

```
{host:item.min(#3)} > 15 & {TRIGGER.VALUE} = 0 & {host:item.nodata(30)} = 0
```

If the last 3 values are above 15, the trigger will become PROBLEM if it is currently in OK state. After that it will return to OK state after no more than 30 seconds (either when data is received or nodata() function is processed by timer).